# How to know if I should wrap operations in name_scope or variable_scope for Tensorboard with example

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

When grouping together operations for visualisations there is a large difference between the outputs generated between the two programs below.
The `tf.name_scope` gives double rnn outputs, one inside the `name_scope` and one outside while `tf.variable_scope` gives the clearer representation. How do I know if I must wrap something in variable vs name scopes (besides the obvious case with `get_variable`)?

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("bongo"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,None, 50], name='myxxxx')
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(77)
    drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=0.5)
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop] * 3)

    initial_state = cell.zero_state(33, tf.float32)

with tf.name_scope("alias"):
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell,
        x, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    fw = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/testmodel/1', sess.graph)
```

And

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("bongo"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,None, 50], name='myxxxx')
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(77)
    drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=0.5)
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop] * 3)

    initial_state = cell.zero_state(33, tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope("alias"):
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell,
        x, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    fw = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/testmodel/1', sess.graph)
```

Comment: The code above and below is identical.

Comment: copy paste error, fixed it now be the difference in syntax is minimal still